# How to Delete The Session and cookie in symfony2

Tags: php, html, symfony, session, cookies

what I need

- i Need When user click logout cookie is deleted.
- code is working in chrome , mozilla.
- bug in mozilla ver 30 , Ie 10.

php code

```
     public function flushAction() {
    $service = $this->get('acme.twig.acme_extension');
    $detect=$service->DomainDetect();

    if ($this->get('session')->get('user')) 
    {

        $session = $this->get('session');
        $ses_vars = $session->all();
        foreach ($ses_vars as $key => $value) {
        $session->remove($key);
        }
    }


        if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
        {
        echo $_COOKIE['user'];
        echo "<pre>..........";
        unset($_COOKIE['user']);
        setcookie("user","",time() - 3000,"/",".10times.com");
        }
        if(isset($_COOKIE['user_flag']))
        {
             echo $_COOKIE['user_flag'];
             echo "<pre>..........";
        unset($_COOKIE['user_flag']);
        setcookie("user_flag",'',time() - 3000,"/",".10times.com");
        }
        if(isset($_COOKIE['email']))
        {
             echo $_COOKIE['email'];
               echo "<pre>....";
        unset($_COOKIE['email']);
        setcookie("email",'',time() - 3000,"/",".10times.com");
        }
          if(isset($_COOKIE['name']))
        {
            echo $_COOKIE['name'];
              echo "<pre>.........";
        unset($_COOKIE['name']);
        setcookie("name",'',time() - 3000,"/",".10times.com");
        }
        if(isset($_COOKIE['id']))
        {
             echo $_COOKIE['id'];
               echo "<pre>.........";
        unset($_COOKIE['id']);
        setcookie("id",'',time() - 3000,"/",".10times.com");
        }
        exit;
        //var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$detect))
        {

            header("Location:".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],TRUE,301);   
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location:".$detect,TRUE,301);
            exit;
        }

        exit;


  }
```

Snapshot of Resource

- [image]

  Debug
- i want to delete cookie and session .
- any suggestion are most welcome.
- i make call domainname.com/user/flush.

solution i have tried

```
    $name = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('user', 'default_value');
    $this->getUser()->setAttribute('user', $value);
    $name->getAttributeHolder()->remove('user','','user_flag');
```

- anthor solution

  ```
   if ($this->get('session')->get('user')) 
  {
      $this->get('session')->remove('user');
  }
  ```
- where i want to  delete session of user and user_flag variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
//clear Session
$session->remove('user_id');
$session->clear();
//clear Cookie
public Boolean invalidate(integer $lifetime = null)
public Boolean migrate(Boolean $destroy = false, integer $lifetime = null)
```

**Refer following link:**

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html

Comment: i have tried with if ($this->get('session')->get('user')) 
        {
            $this->get('session')->remove('user');
        } .. but still session is not terminated cookie are deleted

Comment: @user3785613 Are you try " session_destroy();" for session and cookie "setcookie($name, null, time() - 3600, $path);"

Comment: i have tried and updated snapshot i want clear user session but its not working

Comment: you using remove session variable "$session->remove($key);" but it only remove key try "$session->remove($ses_vars[$key]);"

Comment: i have also tried  with this ..but still problem not resolved..clearing session is simple ..but i dig where im wrong

Comment: did you check the if condition is work or not "if ($this->get('session')->get('user')) 
    {}"

Answer (score 4):

I had some other cookies than `REMEMBERME` which should be removed after successful logout. And I found that Symfony already provides the functionality with `delete_cookies` key under `logout` key in `security.yml` file. See the example code in [the official doc for v2.8](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) line 240.

In summary,

```
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        your_name_of_the_firewall:
            ...
            logout:
                ...
                delete_cookies:
                    your_name_of_the_cookie: { path: null, domain: null }
```

I couldn't check for the older version, but at least it has been there since v2.7. For me, the documentation was not so clear enough, and I had to check the code. FYI, it registers `CookieClearingLogoutHandler`, and there is the actual code which deletes the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that's worked for me is:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->clearCookie(\session_name());
```

Or more thoroughly:

```
$params = \session_get_cookie_params();
$response->headers->clearCookie(
    \session_name(), $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], isset($params['httponly'])
);
```